# UISlider bar disappears using auto layout programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I created a UISlider programmatically, and after adding two auto layout constraints the slider bar no longer appears.  I am seeing the nub / circle for the slider, but nothing else.

```
// create slider programmatically

    _sliderFrame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 250.0f, 400.0f);

    _sliderCalibrate = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:_sliderFrame];

    _sliderCalibrate.minimumValue = 1.0f;

    _sliderCalibrate.maximumValue = 100.0f;

    _sliderCalibrate.value = 50.0f;

    // manually specify Auto Layout constraints in code
    [_sliderCalibrate setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    // add slider to view
    [self.view addSubview:_sliderCalibrate];


NSLayoutConstraint *centerSliderX = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_sliderCalibrate
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_sliderCalibrate.superview
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0];

    NSLayoutConstraint *centerSliderY = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_sliderCalibrate
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_sliderCalibrate.superview
                                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                                constant:0.0];
    [_sliderCalibrate.superview addConstraints:@[centerSliderX, centerSliderY]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set any frame when using auto layout, so just create the slider with `[UISlider new]`; Add either a width constraint, or delete the centerX constraint, and add constraints to both edges of the superview to give the slider a non-zero width.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `setFrame`:​ for initializing an object, you don't need to call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:`​ with the argument `NO`  on views that you place manually.

Just remove this line of code.